# Email template with visualforce issue, cannot set test record

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

This is the **error** that I'm faced today, and have no idea where it comes from!

> Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: List has no rows for assignment to SObject. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem.

I'm trying to create an **Email Template for Order Confirmation** email, to just ordered items.

These are all in sandbox.

In Email Template section, button [ **Send Test and Verify Merge Fields** ] does not show the test Orders that I created.

Edit:
I managed to fix the error, but I still can't choose any test orders, it won't show them in look up window.

These are the **steps I took** (I use lightning experience):

Setup / Email / Classic Email Templates:

- added folder "Order Email Templates"
- new template / type: visualforce

template content:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="sub b" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Order">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

<c:OrderContentCmp ></c:OrderContentCmp>

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

codes:

visualforce component named "OrderContentCmp"

```
<apex:component controller="OrderContentController" access="global">

    <h3>Deer {!record.BillToContact.Name},</h3>
    <p>Tank u for buying stuff, and yes this means if we don't review our email content, we're doomed.</p>
    <hr/>

    <h3>Order Details</h3>
    <hr/>
    <p>Order # {!record.OrderNumber}</p>
    <p>Placed on {!record.CreatedDate}</p>

    <!-- ITEMS -->

</apex:component>
```

controller

```
public with sharing class OrderContentController {

    private String mOrderId;
    public Order record { get; private set; }

    public List<OrderItem> items { get; private set; }

    public OrderContentController() {
        mOrderId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        record = [SELECT Id,OrderNumber,BillToContact.Name,Account.Name FROM Order WHERE Id=:mOrderId];
        items = [SELECT Id,Product2.Name,Quantity,UnitPrice,TotalPrice FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId=:mOrderId];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution is:

```
<c:OrderContentCmp orderId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
```

and the component itself

```
<apex:component controller="OrderContentController" access="global">
  <apex:attribute name="orderId" assignto="{!recordId}" type="ID" 
     description="..." required="true"/>
  .... markup
  ... markup for items uses this notation (or datatable equiv) 
    <apex:repeat value="{!record.OrderItems}" var="oi">
        ...
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component/>
```

and the VF component controller

```
public with sharing class OrderContentController {
   public ID recordId {get; set;}
   public Order record {
     get {
         return recordId == null
           ? new Order() // avoid exceptions in Preview
           : [select Id, ... , 
               (select id, ... FROM OrderItems)
              FROM Order where Id = :recordId][0];
         }
     private set;

}
```

The component should be passed all the information it needs via the argument list as defined by `apex:attribute` and not rely on how / where the component is embedded

The reason for your error is that in Preview, there's no value for the Page Parameter `Id` and your controller bombs out. The solution I provide above deals with that issue